# Jquery didn't work with !text plugin require js with backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I created a template file `home.html` for my home view with a form in it :

```
<form class="adform">
   <input type="button" id="addcompareitem" class="addcompareitem" value="Add compare item" />
</form>
```

This is some code of  my home view :

```
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
     item1.disableCompareBtn();
  },
  render : function(){
     this.$el.html(homeTemplate);
  }
});
return HomeView;
```

Here's `disableCompareBtn` method :

```
this.disableCompareBtn = function(){
    if(compareitems == null || compareitems.length < 2){
        $('#addcompareitem').prop('disabled', true);
        console.log(1);
    }

};
```

Problem : when home view initialize, the button still enable, but the console.log(1) is working.

Any idea what caused this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're running the disable before the HTML even exists. My bet is that if you `console.log($('#addcompareitem'))` you'll get no elements returned to you. Instead, try disabling the buttons immediately after running `this.$el.html(homeTemplate)`.

Just for clarity's sake, initialize is called when something is constructed, and then you call render on the constructed object.